# hyperref problem not working using dvi-ps and ps-pdf

Tags: hyperref

I have problem using the package hyperref. When I compile my tex using dvi-ps and ps-pdf, the link is created but nothing happened when I click on the link. However, it works when I use pdflatex. I have tried to define the driver dvips but it is still not working.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\Blindtext
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dummy entry}
{\huge {\bf Dummy entry}}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}
{\huge {\bf Foreword}}

\Blindtext
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dummy entry}
{\huge {\bf Dummy entry}}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\end{document}

How I include the pdfs? I am not too sure about this. What I did is just compile the tex file using Latex, then dvi-ps, ps-pdf. The link is not giving me any response. However, PDFLATEX works well.

Comment: Ehm... instead of write a comment, edit your own question and add it, check the link above if you don`t know how. But basically if you type 4 spaces before the texts, this looks like code. -_\

Comment: thanks for the advice. Do you have any idea why does this happen?

Comment: No, but why do you use dvi-ps and ps-pdf for compile and not directly pdflatex for get the pdf? Is there any good reason for that? And you forget the _preamble_ on your MWE, you must start with `\documentaclass{...}` if not it's impossible to know what are you doing.

Comment: Edited. Because that is the way usually I did. And I am using eps figure in my tex file, and PDFLATEX does not support eps figure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you should read the [package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), in fact the section 1, where you can  read about it. Perhaps it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use eps files together with pdflatex. In a modern texsystem you only need to load `\usepackage{epstopdf}`. Or convert your eps to pdf before the compilation.

Beside this: your example doesn't work with pdflatex either as your `\addcontentsline` commands have no sensible anchor. Use `\phantomsection`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Foreword}

\Blindtext
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dummy entry}
{\huge {\bf Dummy entry}}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\end{document}
```